Fortify scanning fails for c++ files
I need scan my folder with c++ files using the Fortify Static Code Analyzer.
I tried, first of all, to include a script in my .yml file, for translating the files with the sourceanalyzer, here is the script:
      - script: |
          set -euo pipefail
          echo "Translating C++ files"
          find $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/sdk -name "*.cpp" | while read -r file; do
            echo "Translating $file"
            sourceanalyzer -b $(Build.BuildId) g++ -c "$file"
          done
        displayName: Translate C++ files

This task executes in the pipeline without errors. I get the output:
Translating C++ files
Translating /__w/1/s/sdk/libs/src/data/eval/BooleanEvalContext.cpp
Translating /__w/1/s/sdk/libs/src/data/eval/EvalLocation.cpp
Translating /__w/1/s/sdk/libs/src/data/eval/EnvAction.cpp

and so on, with all the files.
After this script, I added the FortifySCA@7 task:
      - task: FortifySCA@7
        inputs:
          applicationType: 'other'
          runBuildTranslate: false
          fortifyBuildId: '$(Build.BuildId)'
          runFortifyClean: false
          runFortifyRulepackUpdate: true
          scaVerbose: true
          scaDebug: false
          fortifyScanType: 'LocalScan'
          runFortifyUpload: true
          fortifyServerName: 'Fortify Software Security Center'
          fortifyApplicationName: $(fortifyApplication)
          fortifyApplicationVersion: $(fortifyApplicationVersion)

But when the FortifySCA@7 task is executed, it fails, and I get the error: [error]: No valid input files were specified..
Please, could you help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!
